# WPF datagrid in usercontrol

Tags: wpf

```
        <DataGrid  Width="auto"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Name="dgData" >

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HODAppID}" Width="75" Header="HOD APPID" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Req}"   Header="CandidateID" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Req}"  Header="RequisitionNo" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Candidate}" Width="1.3*" Header="CANDIDATE NAME" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Req}" Width="*" MinWidth="200"  Header="REQUIREMENT"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding status}" Width="80" Header="Status" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding daysopen}" Width="120" x:Name="noDays" Header="# of Days Open" />
```

hi i have  a datagrid , something like above, i was trying to get cell value in column noDays, and change the fore color based on the value in it.please help in this regard.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a converter using `IValueConverter` and add it to your noDays column `Foreground` property. The converter should return a brush value based on the value of the `daysopen` property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

**EDIT:**

Apparently `IValueConverter` doesn't work straight on `DataGridTextColumn`. More info and an example can be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/77a9f317-d0be-4aed-9dc9-9917ad98ffc8.